# replacement symbols to line break (\n) and add the three first columns from the line start

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have a log file with text:

```
Jan 10 09:56:17  1484207777.225918 GET "8.8.8.8" "curl/7.27.0" #0121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.8.9" "curl/7.21.0" #0121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.22.0"
Jan 10 19:59:17  1484207777.225456 GET "8.8.6.8" "curl/7.24.0" #0121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.21.0" #0121484207777.226425 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.22.0"
```

I need replace symbols "#" to line break (\n) and add date/time from this line.

I need result:

```
Jan 10 09:56:17  1484207777.225918 GET "8.8.8.8" "curl/7.27.0" 
Jan 10 09:56:17  0121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.8.9" "curl/7.21.0" 
Jan 10 09:56:17  0121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.22.0"
Jan 10 19:59:17  1484207777.225456 GET "8.8.6.8" "curl/7.24.0" 
Jan 10 19:59:17  0121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.21.0" 
Jan 10 19:59:17  0121484207777.226425 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.22.0"
```

I tried with sed, but without result.

```
for a in $(cat logs)

do

b=$(cat logs | awk '{print $1, $2, $3}')

echo "$a" | sed 's/#/\n"$b"/g'

done
```

Can you help me please with this task?

Comment: What are the delimiters? are there tabs after the date field, or is everything space-delimited?

Comment: delimiters between lines in log file - line translation (\n).
Yes, everywhere separated by a space.

Comment: awk -F '  +'  '{n = split($2,a,"#"); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1,a[i]}' logs
worked if I have in logs file two space between date and text, but I have only one=(

Answer (score 4):

If your date field is followed by *multiple* spaces while the other fields are separated by *single* spaces as shown in your example, then you could do

```
$ awk -F'  +' '{n = split($2,a,"#"); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1,a[i]}' log
Jan 10 09:56:17 1484207777.225918 GET "8.8.8.8" "curl/7.27.0"
Jan 10 09:56:17 0121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.8.9" "curl/7.21.0"
Jan 10 09:56:17 0121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.22.0"
Jan 10 19:59:17 1484207777.225456 GET "8.8.6.8" "curl/7.24.0"
Jan 10 19:59:17 0121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.21.0"
Jan 10 19:59:17 0121484207777.226425 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.22.0"
```

More generally, you could substitute the `#` as follows

```
$ awk '{gsub(/#/, sprintf("\n%s %s %s ", $1, $2, $3))} 1' log
Jan 10 09:56:17  1484207777.225918 GET "8.8.8.8" "curl/7.27.0"
Jan 10 09:56:17 0121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.8.9" "curl/7.21.0"
Jan 10 09:56:17 0121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.22.0"
Jan 10 19:59:17  1484207777.225456 GET "8.8.6.8" "curl/7.24.0"
Jan 10 19:59:17 0121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.21.0"
Jan 10 19:59:17 0121484207777.226425 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.22.0"
```

Comment: steeldriver, sorry, in log file between data and text only one space.
In this case you command not work=(

Answer (score 0):

A small python script can do the job:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    timestamp = "\n" + " ".join(line.strip().split()[0:3])
    print(line.replace('#',timestamp),end="")
```

And demo of how it works:

```
$ ./break_lines.py < input.txt                                                                                           
Jan 10 09:56:17  1484207777.225918 GET "8.8.8.8" "curl/7.27.0" 
Jan 10 09:56:170121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.8.9" "curl/7.21.0" 
Jan 10 09:56:170121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.22.0"
Jan 10 19:59:17  1484207777.225456 GET "8.8.6.8" "curl/7.24.0" 
Jan 10 19:59:170121484207777.226639 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.21.0" 
Jan 10 19:59:170121484207777.226425 GET "8.8.5.9" "curl/7.22.0"
```

Explanation of how it works is simple - we break line into words, and take first 3 words and join them together into a string which has newline attached in front of it after that we simply replace `#` with that new string - and viola !